# What should we do with posts closed as too immodest?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, modesty-policy

Sometimes a post will be closed based on our modesty policy. What should we do with such questions after they are closed, since arguably, their existence while closed is also too immodest? On the other hand, though, we may want to give the question a chance to edit itself to bring it back in line with the policy. So how should we handle this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the policy should take into account if the question itself is illicit, or if the question by its nature elicits illicit answers.

In the former case, I think that the logical consequence of our modesty policy should mean that we delete the question itself. The mod who deletes it could leave a comment to the poster explaining why and how it violated the modesty policy, and he could fix it if he wishes.

In the latter case, I think deleting the illicit answers and closing the question is appropriate.

Comment: If I could vote on my own posts, I'd give myself +1 for "elicits illicit"

Answer (score 5):

I propose that all answers (as well as any comments on the question which provide info for answers) should be deleted by the mods on those questions. If the question is ever reopened, someone should flag that material so it can be undeleted. But while it is closed, all answers should be deleted. This would greatly reduce the public presentation of immodest material and still allow for salvageable questions to be salvaged and certain questions to be left as examples of closed questions. And what's the point of closing a question for this reason when it has effectively already been answered and whose answer(s) can continue to be edited?

---

Note: this post can apply in conjunction with any other posts advocating deletion of some or all of the question closed as immodest. If you agree with deleting the answers, vote this post up even if you also think [some] questions should be deleted too.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that you should note the point about the 20k+ users in the post or leave the comments about it.

Comment: @Yez You mean note explicitly that high rep users can see deleted posts? Isn't that just well known?

Comment: Well, to note that it is an acknowledged issue which you feel is OK because part of their being trusted users is their discretion in not viewing things which may be undesirable to them to view.

Answer (score -2):

We shouldn't delete anything. Closing is enough since it indicates communal disapproval and stops most visible discussion.

Comment: I don't support this.