# How can I suppress the appearance of closed questions?

Tags: support

Questions that are closed still appear on the page I see from MY.
When they are immodest, I would rather they did not appear (e.g. [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127116/sexual-intercourse-without-penetration)). How can I suppress the appearance of closed questions?

related: [What should we do with posts closed as too immodest?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/what-should-we-do-with-posts-closed-as-too-immodest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not foolproof, the "Ignore Tag" feature is useful here. You can specify certain tags to be ignored, and then you can choose whether questions with ignored tags appear grayed out or do not appear at all. You could use this for tags that are to be of the sort that you consider immodest, e.g. perhaps the [sexuality](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) tag. You can find the ignore tags feature on the right sidebar just above the list of Hot Network Questions:

[image: Screenshot of ignored tags section of sidebar]

Simply click "Add an ignored tag" and then type the tag you want to ignore and click "Add". Make sure to select the "Hide" option instead of the "Gray out" option in order to remove the questions entirely:

[image: Screenshot of tag added to ignored tag]

This is not a perfect solution. If immodest questions are posted using different tags it will not help, and it will also block all questions with that tag even if the question is not immodest.

Comment: Thanks, useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can vote to delete the question by clicking Delete right below the question, like I just did. I believe 3 votes are enough to delete it and believe it will then disappear completely from the page.

Alternatively a moderator could delete it without the full set of votes (and you could ping them in chat).